# IntelliJ: How to set log levels for tests

Tags: spring-boot, logging, intellij-idea, junit, log-level

I have a problem with test console output in IntelliJ 2016.
When I run JUnit tests via IntelliJ, the console window is flooded with enormous amounts of log lines, for example

```
DEBUG reactor.ipc ....
DEBUG io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil ....
```

It's a simple Spring-Boot application which uses the default logging - I think it's slf4j.
I tried setting

```
logging.level.reactor.ipc=WARN
```

in my `src/main/resources/application.properties` and also setting

`-Dlogging.level.root=WARN` on the RunConfig's VM arguments, but neither has any effect on the log output.
What is the correct place to configure logging verbosity when executing Tests from Intellij?

Answer (score 21):

You can fill up file named logback.xml in src/test/resources with sample content like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d %5p | %t | %-55logger{55} | %m %n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <level value="TRACE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

to have TRACE logging level. You can change this log level to meet your needs.